# Unit testing with UIWebView

Tags: iphone, unit-testing, xcode4, uiwebview, ocunit

When creating an UIWebView inside an unit test I get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`:

```
-(void)test1 {
    [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];  // EXC_BAD_ACCESS
}
```

Is there a special configuration to run units test that involve UIWebView?

I'm using OCUnit/SenTest on XCode 4.2.

Comment: I get occasional EXC_BAD_ACCESS when debugging on the simulator, but never when running on the device. I suspect a bug :/

Comment: I have the same exact problem! I thought it was just me. Maybe you can't test UIWebView?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently this only happens when unit testing a static library directly. Most likely whatever `UIWebView` needs is not loaded with an empty `test host`.

When unit testing an app this doest not occur.

Comment: So, is there any way to test using a UIWebView in a static library? I added UIKit to the Build Settings of the static library, but I'm still getting this EXC_BAD_ACCESS any time I try to run the test.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an app target that is just for running your unit tests. Create a new empty application in the same workspace and set this as the Target for the unit test target. I call my app TestRunner.

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on this? This seems like a reasonable solution. But did you mean an empty app within the same project or is there a better way to go about setting this up?

Comment: I added a screenshot that shows where the target is configured.

Comment: It was the "empty application" part I didn't quite get. But now that I've got it to work, I realized all you meant was a shell application that has no features (empty methods... etc) that just compiles which then allows itself to be "targeted" by our tests to run on. This totally works and is a viable solution. Thanks!

Comment: Just to follow up here. I got the full test suite to work. Luckily this particular project is open source, and the code/methodology can be found in this repro: https://github.com/BlueKai/bluekai-ios-sdk/tree/master/sdk

Comment: Doesn't help me. I receive `GuardMalloc[UnitTestRunner-16080]: could not allocate new zone: (os/kern) no space available` instead of `uardMalloc[xctest-16321]: could not allocate new zone: (os/kern) no space available`.